# Проблема с обновлением Scikit-learn до версии 0.20.1

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, conda

Необходимо обновить Scikit-learn для Anaconda до версии 0.20.1. На данный момент стоит версия 0.19.1. При вводе команды `conda update scikit-learn`выводится: `#All requested packages already installed`. 
Уже пробовал `conda update conda` - обновил, но это проблему не решило. Также попробовал скачать необходимую версию с https://anaconda.org/anaconda/scikit-learn, но при установке выдаёт только ту же 0.19.1. Ещё попробовал написать `conda update scikit-learn=0.20.1`, но в этом случае `Solving environment: \` "крутиться" бесконечно (пол часа точно).
Как же всё-таки обновить эту библиотеку?

Comment: какая у вас OS, какая версия и архитектура/битность Python?

Comment: Python 3 ('32bit', 'WindowsPE')

Comment: Python 3.?? В общем, ищите подходящую версию [здесь](http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, я обновил python командой `conda update python` (версия 3.6.5). Снова попробовал обновить scikit-learn - выдаёт ту же 0.19.1. Снёс к чертям `conda remove scikit-learn` и снова установил `conda install scikit-learn`. Алилуя, выдал версию аж 0.20.2